# Reading iPhone Information (VB.NET)

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, vb.net

Has anyone found out a way to read the device which is plugged in and return a serial number for that device?

For example, I am wanting to read my iPhone Serial Number which is plugged into a USB Port, I am wanting my application to tell me my serial number for that device.

Is there a way to do this??

Thank You

J Mahone

Comment: You can get it from iTunes when the device is connected.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is an option, is there no way that a application that I make can do it?

Comment: See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt you could get it via USB. You CAN write a small iOS App (like add one line of code to an Xcode App created with New Project) to get it and NSLog it, using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

As per the docs, this is deprecated and may not be supported in future. Also, if you try to submit ANY app that uses this to the App store, it will be rejected during review. This doesn't apply to Enterprise Apps, only Apps submitted to the store. And nothing stopping you from writing one for your own use.

The 'Approved' device ID now is Advertising ID.

Also... now that I think about it, if you search around in the iOS App store for UUID you will find a bunch of FREE Apps that will display that information on the screen for your device.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that on XCode for the Mac, it seems very advanced coding for me, but I will give it a try!!

Comment: Just get a free app. Also, as you are newbie... if the answer helped you, you should mark this as the correct answer. It may not have been the answer you wanted but it IS most likely the answer.